# Do we want to unpin the accepted answer from the top?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Stack Exchange recently [changed the way answers are sorted on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352), meaning that accepting an answer no longer pins it to the top (regardless of sorting method). It still has the green check-mark next to it, and accepting an answer is still exactly the same for the purposes of reputation, badges, green marker next to a question, etc.

Stack Exchange is also [asking the other sites in the network whether they'd like this behaviour or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568), as this is now a site-configurable setting.

Does anyone on this site have a preference?

Comment: My vote is to unpin it like SO have. The new sorting feels more intuitive to me

Comment: Yes, unpin the accepted answer.